# Why do we need contour integrals if we can simply map the function given over from the complex plane to the real plane and integrate normally?

Tags: calculus, integration, contour-integration, parametrization

> A **curve** in the complex plane is defined as a continuous function from a closed interval of the real line to the complex plane $z:[a,b]\to\mathbb C$.

This is just a locus definition and can be mapped to the real plane.
$$\int_a^bf(t)\,dt=\int_a^b(u(t)+iv(t))\,dt=\int_a^bu(t)\,dt+i\int_a^bv(t)\,dt$$
I do not understand why we need to name these sets of integrals contours integrals when it is just vector calculus and parametric integration because complex numbers are just vectors. We could just integrate over the real plane and get our answer. Why couldn't we just call it that? I am confused as to the significance of referring to these as "contours" and having a special integral sign.
$$\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,dt$$

Comment: Every line or surface integral is ultimately an ordinary integral w.r.t. real parameters. Since here we integrate a "vector valued" function $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ against the increments $dz$ over a contour $\gamma$, imho the name contour integral is more than justified.

Comment: "Why couldn't we just call it that?" isn't a mathematical question. :) But to add to Kurt's comment, when an integrand is _holomorphic_, the value of an integral is invariant under "topological deformation" of the contour, e.g., deforming the contour by homotopy or substituting a homologous chain. To say "[I]t is just vector calculus and parametric integration because complex numbers are just vectors" is to overlook a fundamental _topological_ property of complex analysis.

Comment: Contour integrals are quite different, in a subtle way, to the path integrals you see in vector calculus. In this case, the $\mathrm dz$-term, which turns into $\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm dt$ carries information about the direction in which the path goes - note you end up doing a complex multiplication. In particular, if you integrate a constant around a loop you will get zero - facts like this lead to a very rich theory of contour integration, with incredibly useful results like the residue theorem. For this useful theory, it's helpful to define the notion of contour integral.

Answer (score 1):

I will elaborate on Izaak's comment.

Note that if $f=u+iv$ and $\gamma=\gamma_1 +i\gamma_2$, you get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma f(z) dz
&= \int_a^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,dt \\
&= \int_a^b (u+iv)(\gamma(t))(\gamma_1'+i\gamma_2')(t)\,dt \\
&= \int_a^b [u(\gamma(t))\gamma_1'(t)-v(\gamma(t))\gamma_2'(t)]\,dt
+i\int_a^b [u(\gamma(t))\gamma_2'(t)+v(\gamma(t))\gamma_1'(t)]\,dt
\end{align}
$$
which is not quite the same as what you would get in vector calculus. Treating $f$ and $\gamma$ as vector functions, you wouldn't be able to write the integrand $f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)$ because that would require you to know how to multiply the vectors $f(\gamma(t))$ and $\gamma'(t)$. In vector calculus instead of the complex multiplication you use a dot product:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma f\cdot d\vec s
&=\int_\gamma f(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)\,dt \\
&=\int_a^b u(\gamma(t))\gamma_1'(t)\,dt +\int_a^b v(\gamma(t))\gamma_2'(t)\,dt
\end{align}
$$