# Non-physical Intution for line integrals/complex path integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Intuition for complex (or possibly more generally over paths $\gamma(t): [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ or $\psi(t): [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb C$.

I'm struggling to understand what is happening when integrating over $\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz$, a complex path integral, or when similarly for over a path in $\mathbb R^2$.

When taking a line integral that is a 3d path, I understand it as it is just the area underneath the curve when "stretched out", just like a normal 1 dimensional integral that you'd learn in calculus I. Any explanation I can find generally uses terms from physics like "work" or "flow" which I am woefully unfamiliar with.

Comment: Apologies if this has already been asked

Comment: Just to be clear, you are looking for an non-rigorous, intuitive or geometric interpretation/explanation of the contour integral that does not borrow intuition from physics?

Comment: Yeah, I haven't learned as much physics (read: any) since I was in high school, and most of the explanations don't make much sense to me - maybe if I tried a little harder I'd understand it...

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4540803/949989) contains great comments and answers.

Comment: @Kurt G. I'll check it out, thanks.